# depend on apache commons codec

Tags: java, maven

I try to add an dependency on Maven to the Apache common codec repository (version 1.15). I am using the syntax from the [Apache website](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/dependency-info.html#Apache_Maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

If I run the code I get the Error: `java: package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist`
My Editor (IntelliJ IDEA) marks the repository as not found: `Dependency 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15' not found`
Maven is on online mode.

How could I get the repository?

Comment: I tried to reproduce that and cannot.  Which repositories have you configured your build to resolve dependencies from?

Comment: That artifact exists in Maven central ([link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.15/commons-codec-1.15.jar)). So the most likely reason for this not to work is that you're not using that repository.

Comment: Does your build work on plain command line ?